# What's the best design for a RESTful URI with multiple mandatory parameters?

Tags: python, web-services, rest, uri

I'm looking to see if more of the seasoned web service veterans can comment on the best way to design a RESTful URI in where I need mandatory parameters.  Case in point, I'd like to design an URI that requests data:

```
example.com/request/distribution
```

However, from my understanding is that the approach is that more data should return at the higher levels while more detailed data would be returned if applying more specific URI keywords but in my case, I need at least 3 values for that to happen.  Those 3 values would be a date value, an account value and proprietary distribution code values.  For example:

```
example.com/request/distribution?acct=123&date=20030102&distcode=1A;1B;1C
```

Is that considered an "RESTful" URL or is there a better approach that would make more sense?  Any input is greatly appreciated.

BTW, Python is the language of choice.  Thanks!

Comment: So what happens when someone enters just an acct and a date?  Do they get 3 "distribution" resources (1A, 1B, 1C), or maybe more?  To put the question another way, are those paramters ways to narrow down the data, and you need all three to uniquely identify a resource?  What if a given user only has 1 such resource?

Comment: You know what's funny is that I discussed this sort of thinking with my wife.  I think the approach that I'm going to take is that if the end-user doesn't provide the resource element that I require, a "default" one would be in place.  For example, if the "distcode" parameters are omitted, then a default value of "XY;XZ;CX;1X;2X;3X" would be assumed.  Going further, if the date was omitted, then I would used today's date.  Going even further, if the account was omitted, then I would use a value of "0" which indicates ALL accounts in my system.  I think this design works well for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URI's cannot, by definition, be "unRESTful" of themselves because the URI specification was guided by the REST architectural style. How you *use* a URI can violate the REST style by:

1. Not following the "client-server" constraint; for example, by using WebSockets to implement server push.
2. Not following the "identification of resources" constraint; for example, using a portion of the URI to specify control data or resource metadata rather than stick to identifying a resource, or by identifying resource via some mechanism other than the URI (like session state or other out-of-band mechanisms).
3. Not following the "manipulation of resources through representations" constraint; for example, by using the querystring portion of a URI to transfer state.
4. Not following the "self-descriptive messages" constraint; for example, using HTTP GET to modify state, or transferring JSON with a Content-Type of "text/html".
5. Not following the "hypermedia as the engine of application state" constraint; for example, not providing the user agent hyperlinks to follow, but instead assuming it will construct them using out-of-band knowledge.
6. Not following the "layered system" constraint, by requiring the client to know details about the innards of how the server works (especially requiring the client to provide them in a request).

None of the above are necessarily *bad choices*. They might be the best choice for your system because they foster certain architectural properties (such as efficiency or security) . They're just not part of the REST style.

The fact that your resource is identified by multiple mandatory segments is part and parcel of the design of URI's. As Anton points out, the choice between `example.com/request/distribution?acct=123&date=20030102&distcode=1A;1B;1C` and, say, `example.com/accounts/123/distributions/20030102/1A;1B;1C` is purely one of data design, and not a concern at the URI layer itself. There is nothing wrong, for example, with responding to a PUT, POST, or DELETE request to the former. A client which failed to follow a link to either one would be considered broken. A system which expected either one to be made available to the client by some means other than a hypermedia response would be considered "unRESTful".

Comment: I think the more I digest your post, the more its starting to make sense to me.  I believe this is what I was looking for, +1 for you.

Comment: Your points are correct—although clarity, readability, and stability of endpoints are important in APIs, which is why it still matters which parameters you put into URI hierarchy. And since the question was about the best (not, say, “technically valid”) design for a RESTful URI with mandatory parameters, these points probably apply as well, although aren't as on-topic as yours. =)

Answer (score 3):

It's better to go about creating RESTful API in terms of resources first, not URIs. It has more to do with your data design than, say, with your language of choice.

E.g., you have a Distribution resource. You want to represent it in your web-based API, so it needs to have an appropriate unique resource identifier (URI). It should be simple, readable, and unlikely to change. This would be a decent example:

```
http://example.com/api/distribution/<some_unique_id>
```

**Think twice before putting more things and hierarchy into your URIs**.

You don't want to change your URIs as your data model or authentication scheme evolve. Changing URIs is [uncool](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) and pain for you and developers that use your API. So, if you need to pass authentication to the back-end, you probably should use GET parameters or HTTP headers (AWS S3 API, for example, [allows both](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth)).

Putting too much into GET parameters (e.g., `http://example.com/api/distribution/?id=<some_unique_id>`) may seem like a bad idea, but IMO it doesn't really matter[0]—as long as you keep your API documentation accessible and up-to-date.

[0] Update: For read-only APIs, at least. For CRUD APIs, as @daniel has pointed out, it's more convenient when you have endpoints like in the first example above. That way you can nicely use HTTP methods by enabling GET, PUT, DELETE for individual resources at `/api/distribution/<id>`, and POST to `/api/distribution` to create new distributions.

While researching the answer, found a nice presentation about RESTful APIs: [**Designing HTTP Interfaces and RESTful Web Services**](http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services-phpday11-20110514).

Comment: Wait, I'm lost.  I thought the whole purpose of a RESTful call is to provide a service where you can query any data resource, hence the change in URIs.  In my particular scenario, distribution is the base URI and the rest is data that can be queried by the client.  One client can conceivably have hundreds of thousands of accounts with varying dates.  I won't even go to the amount of distribution codes I have.  My thought would be to clearly outline how to make a proper GET request to pull data for any inbound parameter they want.  The whole unique ID thing threw me.

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  I take it you were talking about the whole "API Key", correct?

Comment: +1 for "You don't want to change your URIs as your data model...evolve[s]".  This is a really great answer.

Comment: +1 for "distribution/{id}" as a generally-useful design. It allows you to change even some of the "mandatory details" in the future if needed. And you can always redirect from the longer URL to the shorter.

Comment: @mastashake57 Well yes, RESTful API does provide an access to resources… Which is where my understanding ends. =( I don't think I get what you mean by “distribution is base URI and the rest is data that can be queried”, for example. What are the resources (maybe accounts and distribution codes?), how they relate to each other? I'd suggest to define resources you plan to expose through API before you design URIs, if you want to go RESTful.

Comment: What I *think* I meant to say was that RESTful allows me to GET data depending on the resources I provide it.  I would think that example.com/api/distribution/123/20120101/ab;bc;cd;ef is a valid request.  So is, example.com/api/distribution/321/19990101/xa;xb;xc.  My question is what does <some_uniq_id> come in to play?

Comment: It is a valid request anyway. It's more of a matter of taste and data design, so I realized it probably is out of scope of your question… I wouldn't normally put such hierarchy into the URI. <some_uniq_id> is one global identifier I'd use, instead of account + date + key. But your approach probably makes sense, depending on your particular case.

Comment: (The confusion also may arise since I've thought more about “typical” RESTful web services with URI schemes like described by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services).)

Answer (score 0):

The RESTful way is to represent the data as a resource, not parameters to a request:

```
example.com/distribution/123/20030102/1A;1B;1C
```

Comment: This is interesting and it was in the direction I was going to, initially.  However, I thought that because the RESTful way to retrieve data is based upon the idea that the less resources you submit, the broader the data.  My problem is that I can't do that as that I need those 3 parameters as mandatory or is that not even relevant at this point?

Comment: Also, I was thinking of incorporating an "API Key" mechanism.  That being said, would this still be considered restful?  example.com/distribution?apikey=abcdefg12345/123/20030102/1A;1B;1C

Comment: Embedding an API key in a url sounds like a bad idea. Go for a Authorization: header instead.

Comment: Can you explain why?  My end-game is to provide this service via SSL within private WAN links.  Also, this article seems to think it's a good idea: http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/rest-api-authentication-schemes

Comment: I think @Evert means putting API key in URL hierarchy, which doesn't make much sense, as it isn't a part of resource identifier. Putting it into GET query is probably fine (just as an example, Amazon S3 API [supports](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationExamples) both query string authentication and `Authorization:` header).

Answer (score -1):

When you think about RESTful, most of the times you also should think about CRUD.

```
example.com/request/distribution?acct=123&date=20030102&distcode=1A;1B;1C
```

is fine for a GET-Request to show something (The R in CRUD).

But what URLs do you consider for the CUD-Parts?

Comment: Well, I'm still thinking about the other elements (CUD) but right now, I'm researching on performing just read-only extracts.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: There's nothing illegal about requesting a POST, PUT, or DELETE to a URI that possesses a query string. Query string parameters serve to identify the resource just as much as any other part of the URI. It's only decades of HTML forms that have ingrained in us the idea that query strings and POST are mutually exclusive.